# Azure Maps - Cannot see the map

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I was following this tutorial
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-your-first-iot-central-app/)
In unit 4, I followed all the steps but what I could see was just a blank page like this

[Unit 4 exercise result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwBcX.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add a reference to the Azure Maps Services Module JavaScript file. -->
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas-service.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function GetMap() {
            //Instantiate a map object
            var map = new atlas.Map("myMap", {
                //Add your Azure Maps subscription key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: 'mB~~~~~~(I wrote my maps primary key here)'
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #myMap {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Azure Maps Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itcGP.png)

This feedback page also doesn't work...
(https://feedback.azuremaps.com/)

[Feedback Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1X7i.png)

Also, in this website, when I press "Open In New Tab", I cannot see anything...
(https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/)

[Code samples Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9V7e.png)

I had spent almost 4 hours but couldn't find out the solution...
What should I need to do to see proper Maps on those pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the different sites that use Azure Maps doesn't work for you its likely one of the following reasons:

- Make sure you are in a supported region. Azure Maps is not available to users who are located in China or South Korea, and the requests to the platform are actively blocked.
- You are using an unsupported browser: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/supported-browsers
- WebGL is either disabled in your browser, or isn't working. Try this sample: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Map/Detect%20if%20browser%20is%20supported.html
- Your graphic card has issues, try updating the drivers.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was due to my location. Will it be available when I use VPN?

Answer (score 0):

check how the map starts

> ```
>  $(document).ready(function () {
>     InitMap();
> });
> ```

```
function InitMap() {

    var map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
        center: [-73.98235, 40.76799],
        zoom: 10,
        language: 'en-US',
        authOptions: {
            authType: 'subscriptionKey',
            subscriptionKey: 'key1*****'
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    InitMap();
});
```